# Show some comment fields to comment author and node authors only

Tags: drupal, permissions, comments, field, private

I have a Drupal site and would like to make some comment fields (for the content type "event") only seen by the comment author and the comment node author. These fields are, "field_how_to_redeem_this_offer", "field_date" and "comment_body". I tried using the module, Private Comments but that only gives you the option to make the whole comment private, not just some of the fields. So, I had a developer create a custom module and it works except, when creating a new comment the fields I specified above are not shown and they should be. I'm guessing that's because when creating a new comment the comment author has not been assigned yet so I need to change the code so that when a new comment is being created (or comment form is viewed), all fields should be available to the user. Is there a way to do this? Please see the code bellow:

```
`function bidonmybash_field_access($op, $field, $entity_type, $entity, $account) {
 global $user;
 $fields = array('field_how_to_reedem_this_offer','field_date','comment_body');
 if (in_array($field['field_name'],$fields)) {
 if ($entity) {
 if (isset($entity->node_type)) {
  if ($entity->node_type == 'comment_node_event') {
    $cuid = $entity->uid;
    $node = node_load($entity->nid);
    $nuid = $node->uid;
    if ($user->uid == $cuid || $user->uid == $nuid) {
      return TRUE;
    }
    else {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
 }
}
 }
 }`
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd think you could just add

```
!$cuid
```

so it looks like

```
if (!$cuid || $user->uid == $cuid || $user->uid == $nuid)
```

since $cuid should be undefined when the comment is new.